# null character error while trying to create method

Tags: java, methods

I'm very new to Java and having some trouble with an assignment. I need to create a method that checks a double value and if it greater than $700.00 then a 15% discount is applied to the courseFeesInCAD variable and sets a boolean value to true. Otherwise there is not discount and the boolean value is set to (or stays) as false. My issue with the code below (other than inexperience) is that it give an illegal character: \u0000 error.

I believe that \u0000 is null CHAR but I don't have any char type variables. It seems to have an issue with the line `"public void setDiscount(){"`

```
 public void setDiscount()
if(courseFeesInCad > 700.00){
courseFeesInCAD = courseFeesInCAD *0.85
isEligibleForDiscount = true;
System.Out.println("Your discounted course cost is: "+ (courseFeesInCAD));
```

The rest of my program compile and runs as expected when I comment out that line.

Comment: Missing brackets after function?

Comment: braces, semicolon missing in the code you have provided

Comment: And also System.Out.println  should be System.out.println

Comment: I edited the question in order to fix obvious errors. Can you re-test and tell us if you still have the problem ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Shouldn't that be an answer instead of an edit?

Comment: Could you clarify *exactly* what you mean by "it give an illegal character: \u0000 error"? Do you mean at compile-time? If so, I suspect it's complaining about the *source code* rather than a `char` variable. I suspect that somehow your source code has a U+0000 character in it. I'd suggest deleting the line the compiler is complaining about, and retyping it.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to stackoverflow and wasn't certain how to properly enter my code so I retyped it (in a hurry). In my code it does have the semi-colon and proper braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have forgotten to surround your body code with brackets {}. also on line 3 you forgot a semicolon. If you fix these issues, your code should work fine. I hope this helps!

EDIT:

The fixed code should appear as so:

```
public void setDiscount() {
    if (courseFeesInCAD > 700.00) {
        courseFeesInCAD = courseFeesInCAD * 0.85;
        isEligibleForDiscount = true;
        System.out.println("Your discounted course cost is: " + (courseFeesInCAD));
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

Somebody edited your question fixing the braces issue, but you still need to add a semicolon to line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, especially Jon Skeet! Even though I couldn't see any white space of any kind (and held down delete) when I removed the problem line and re-entered, it worked!

Thanks as well to Arnaud for correcting my sloppy coding.

I appreciate all the help.